# Trigger a script in a FreePBX Distro when arbitrary call is picked up

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I am using Asterisk 13.17.0 on a FreePBX 14.0.1.1 distro. I would like to execute a python script whenever a call gets picked up, regardless of whether it is an internal or external one, passing to it as command line parameters the number who's calling and the user who's picking it up. How could I modify my dialplan in order for this to be done? I've tried modifying the `[app-pickup]` extension in `/etc/asterisk/extensions_additional.conf`, but picking up an internal call with this modification was to no avail

Answer (score 0):

You should check diall command params, especial G param

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_Dial

```
G( context^exten^priority ) - If the call is answered, transfer the calling party to the specified priority and the called party to the specified priority plus one.

    context
    exten
    priority
```

In freepbx you can change dial params in settings tab.

You also SHOULD NOT ever touch extensions_additional.conf, it even have warning on top of file. File will be rewrited every time you change config. You have **do changes** in **extensions_custom.conf**